# Filtered 2-colimits commute with finite 2-limits

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, limits-and-colimits, groupoids

Is there an explicit proof anywhere in the literature that filtered 2-colimits commute with finite 2-limits (all meant in the weak bicategorical sense) in the 2-category of groupoids?  I have only been able to find a handful of papers about filtered 2-colimits, notably Dubuc and Street's [A construction of 2-filtered bicolimits of categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605304), and have not found this result in any of them.

Of course one could try to deduce this from $\infty$-categorical results, but the latter proofs are also often sketchy, and in the case of groupoids it ought to be possible to give a concrete constructive proof.

Comment: I agree there exist sketchy $\infty$-categorical proofs in the literature, but I can't think of anything I might try to deduce something like this from which I'd classify as "sketchy"...

Comment: In case it's useful, Theorem 7.24 of Canevali's thesis [2-filtered bicolimits and finite weighted bilimits commute in Cat](http://cms.dm.uba.ar/academico/carreras/licenciatura/tesis/2016) proves the result for categories rather than groupoids. Perhaps the reflectivity of Grpd in Cat is enough to transfer this to groupoids?

Comment: @TimCampion Well, I'm looking at HTT 5.3.3.3, which spends quite a while carefully saying things about projective model structures, but then for the actual meat of the proof just says it "reduces to a classical assertion" without a citation.

Comment: @varkor Thanks, that's terrific!  And the citation to Dupont's [Interchange of filtered 2-colimits and finite 2-limits](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1553) might be even better.  I expect reflectivity isn't even needed if the filtered domains are 1-categories, since groupoids are closed in Cat under all limits and under colimits over 1-categories.  If you post your comment as an answer I would probably accept it.

Comment: @MikeShulman Lurie reduces to the assertion that homotopy cartesian squares of Kan complexes are stable under colimits indexed by directed partially ordered sets, which he refers to as a "classical fact". It's true that such facts about simplicial homotopy theory are regularly used without citation in HTT, but I think they really are classical. For instance here, you just have to observe that since you've got all the maps you need, you can detect homotopy cartesianness by looking at homotopy groups, and that homotopy groups of Kan complexes commute with filtered colimits.

Comment: It may not be a proof which is easily converted into a direct bicategorical proof, but I wouldn't call it "sketchy".

Comment: The classical result is for strictly commutative diagrams, however, so somewhere one is using the fact that diagrams can be strictified…

Comment: @ZhenLin That seems valid. I think the simplest patch is to appeal to Prop 4.2.4.4 (which was used earlier in the proof in a similar way) to see that any functor of $\infty$-categories $\square \times A \to Spaces$ may be represented by a functor of 1-categories $\square \times A \to Kan$, where $\square = [1] \times [1]$ is the walking commutative square and $Kan$ is the category of Kan complexes (and $A$ is the directed poset as in the proof).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two relevant papers are:

- Dupont's [Interchange of filtered 2-colimits and finite 2-limits](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1553).
- Canevali's [2-filtered bicolimits and finite weighted bilimits commute in Cat](http://cms.dm.uba.ar/academico/carreras/licenciatura/tesis/2016).

The former proves that finite conical pseudolimits and filtered pseudolimits commute in $\mathbf{Cat}$; whereas the latter proves the analagous result for finite weighted bilimits and filtered bicolimits.

It may be that these are enough to recover commutivity in $\mathbf{Grpd}$ for the cases in which you are interested.